# sfInvokeAPI Lambda function error UnicodeError: encoding with 'idna' codec failed (UnicodeError: label empty or too long)

Tags: aws-lambda, salesforce

I'm trying to invoke sfInvokeAPI lambda function with a phonelookup test action but following error occured:

> {   "errorMessage": "encoding with 'idna' codec failed (UnicodeError:
> label empty or too long)",   "errorType": "UnicodeError",
> "stackTrace": [
> "  File "/var/task/sfInvokeAPI.py", line 61, in lambda_handler\n    resp = phoneLookup(sf, event['Details']['Parameters']['sf_phone'],
> event['Details']['Parameters']['sf_fields'])\n",
> "  File "/var/task/sfInvokeAPI.py", line 133, in phoneLookup\n    records = sf.parameterizedSearch(data=data)\n",
> "  File "/var/task/salesforce.py", line 98, in parameterizedSearch\n    resp = self.makeRequest(self.request.post,
> **{"url": url, "data": data})\n",
> "  File "/var/task/salesforce.py", line 183, in makeRequest\n    return requestMethod(**kwargs, headers=self.headers)\n",
> "  File "/var/task/salesforce.py", line 212, in post\n    r = requests.post(url=url, data=json.dumps(data), params=params,
> headers=headers)\n",
> "  File "/opt/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 116,
> in post\n    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json,
> **kwargs)\n",
> "  File "/opt/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 60,
> in request\n    return session.request(method=method, url=url,
> **kwargs)\n",
> "  File "/opt/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line
> 533, in request\n    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)\n",
> "  File "/opt/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line
> 646, in send\n    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)\n",
> "  File "/opt/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line
> 449, in send\n    timeout=timeout\n",
> "  File "/opt/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py",
> line 672, in urlopen\n    chunked=chunked,\n",
> "  File "/opt/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py",
> line 376, in _make_request\n    self._validate_conn(conn)\n",
> "  File "/opt/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py",
> line 994, in _validate_conn\n    conn.connect()\n",
> "  File "/opt/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py",
> line 334, in connect\n    conn = self._new_conn()\n",
> "  File "/opt/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py",
> line 157, in _new_conn\n    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout,
> **extra_kw\n",
> "  File "/opt/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py",
> line 61, in create_connection\n    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host,
> port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):\n",
> "  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 752, in getaddrinfo\n    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family,
> type, proto, flags):\n"   ] }

Can anybody tell what's wrong? All configurations are done but still this error is there.